# AttributeError: 'Resource' object has no attribute 'messages'

Tags: python, gmail-api

I am struggling with a weird problem with Google Gmail API(python).
I am trying to send the message, credentials look right(I got redirected to site to accept if I allow the app to manage emails, etc..)

SCOPE: 'https://mail.google.com/'

Code:

```
import httplib2
from apiclient import discovery
def SendMessage(user_id, message):
  """Send an email message.

  Args:
    service: Authorized Gmail API service instance.
    user_id: User's email address. The special value "me"
    can be used to indicate the authenticated user.
    message: Message to be sent.

  Returns:
    Sent Message.
  """
  from GoogleCredentialsMail import get_credentials
  credentials = get_credentials()
  http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
  service = discovery.build('admin', 'directory_v1', http=http)

  message = (service.users().messages().send(userId=user_id,        
   body=message).execute())
  print('Message Id: %s' % message['id'])
  return(message)
```

But I get an error:

```
AttributeError: 'Resource' object has no attribute 'messages'
```

Any suggestions?

Link to the API: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending

Comment: Have you checked out the [Python Quickstart Tutorial](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python#step_3_set_up_the_sample)? As I can see there, the service name that you have to pass is `gmail`and version `v1` for example.

Answer (score 1):

As I was working around with admin directory ( building bot to move in Google APIs ) I got used to using:

```
service = discovery.build('admin', 'directory_v1', http=http)
```

Thanks to Igle I started rethinking it from begin and found that tricky mistake.
I got it to work now and it looks:

```
service = discovery.build('gmail', 'v1', http=http)
```